# List all associate's names from a referred table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `test` which looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| u1_id | u2_id |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
|     3 |     1 |
|     2 |     1 |
|     2 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
```

And, `u1_id` and `u2_id` are both 'foreign keys' to another table `user`:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | n_foo |
|  2 | n_bar |
|  3 | n_baz |
+----+-------+
```

Not sure how to explain this, but:

- In input, I have a single user `id` which can be referenced in `u1_id` or in `u2_id`.
- I'd like to get the associated user to it as defined in table `test` using a join on table `user`.

For user `id = 1`, I should get:

```
n_bar
n_baz
n_bar
```

For user `id = 2`, I should get:

```
n_foo
n_foo
n_baz
```

This may be a common issue but didn't find exactly how to join these two tables using:

- `u1_id` if my input user `id` is in `u2_id` column
- `u2_id` otherwise

I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
   JOIN user 
   ON user.id = test.u1_id 
WHERE test.u1_id = @guid OR 
      test.u2_id = @guid AND 
      CASE 
         WHEN test.u2_id = @guid 
         THEN test.u2_id = test.u1_id 
      END;
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Or may be there is a better way to design these tables, I'm completely open to any suggestions.

Comment: See UNION [ALL]. And let us know how you get on.

Comment: Do you want duplicates in result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, I believe you need following query:

```
SELECT t2.`name` 
FROM `t2`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT IF(@uid = 1, t1.u1_id, t1.u2_id) as `id`
    FROM `t1`
) as `t1`
WHERE t2.id = t1.id and t1.id != @uid;
```

I tried following:

Date base create, I don't know what columns type your are using just for demo:

```
create table t1 (
    u1_id int,
    u2_id int
);
insert into t1 values 
(1,    2),
(3,    1),
(2,    1),
(2,    3);

create table t2 (
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);
insert into t2 values 
(  1 , 'n_foo' ),
(  2 , 'n_bar' ),
(  3 , 'n_baz' );
```

Then Queries:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+-------+-------+
| u1_id | u2_id |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
|     3 |     1 |
|     2 |     1 |
|     2 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t2;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | n_foo |
|    2 | n_bar |
|    3 | n_baz |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @uid = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @uid;
+------+
| @uid |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t2.`name` 
    -> FROM `t2`
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT IF(@uid = 1, t1.u1_id, t1.u2_id) as `id`
    ->     FROM `t1`
    -> ) as `t1`
    -> WHERE t2.id = t1.id and t1.id != @uid;
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| n_baz |
| n_bar |
| n_bar |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SET @uid = 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @uid;
+------+
| @uid |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t2.`name` 
    -> FROM `t2`
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT IF(@uid = 1, t1.u1_id, t1.u2_id) as `id`
    ->     FROM `t1`
    -> ) as `t1`
    -> WHERE t2.id = t1.id and t1.id != @uid;
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| n_foo |
| n_foo |
| n_baz |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Btw, you can change join conditions if it is not what you wanted. But as it give correct results...

Give it a Try!!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT IF(u1.id = @guid, u2.name, u1.name) AS name
FROM test 
JOIN user u1 ON u1.id = test.u1_id 
JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = test.u2_id 
WHERE test.u1_id=@guid OR test.u2_id=@guid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @GrijeshChauhan's schema...

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT u1_id,u2_id FROM t1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT u2_id,u1_id FROM t1
) x
JOIN t2
  ON t2.id = x.u1_id
WHERE x.u2_id = 2;
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| u1_id | u2_id | id   | name  |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |    1 | n_foo |
|     1 |     2 |    1 | n_foo |
|     3 |     2 |    3 | n_baz |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
```